# URL preview image strategy

Tags: meta-tags, preview

I'm trying to implement own URL preview service and I thought the following strategy for figuring out more or less accurate preview image was enough:

- look for `og:image` first
- if no `og:image` was found look for link with  `rel="image_src"` next
- if nothing found, look for first image in a body with preferrable aspect ratio, larger than assumed size (eg. > 50x50).

But looks like there are sites which don't fall in any of these rules yet still having a nice preview generated by slack or facebook. [500px](https://500px.com) is one of them - any hint where following preview images comes from?

[image]

Comment: That website seems to be Ajax loaded through Javascript. You need to get interpreted page after all ajax requests by a middle browser which loads the page and waits for the page to be completed then by getting the interpreted  codes you can start analyzing the source.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour that's true - 500px heavily bases on XHRs but even having the page fully loaded I still can't see where the preview generated by slack/fb comes from. A cache from the past...?